# how to find all possible combinations between tuples without duplicates scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

suppose I have list of tuples:

```
val a = ListBuffer((1, 5), (6, 7))
```

**Update:** Elements in a are assumed to be distinct inside each of the tuples2, in other words, it can be for example `(1,4) (1,5)` but not `(1,1) (2,2)`.

I want to generate results of all combinations of `ListBuffer a` between these two tuples but without duplication. The result will look like:

```
ListBuffer[(1,5,6), (1,5,7), (6,7,1), (6,7,5)]
```

**Update:** elements in result tuple3 are also distinct. tuples them selves are also distinct, means as long as (6,7,1) is present, then (1,7,6) should not be in the result tuple3.

If, for example `val a = ListBuffer((1, 4), (1, 5))` then the result output should be `ListBuffer[(1,4,5)]` in which `(1,4,1) and (1,5,1)` are discarded

How can I do that in Scala?

**Note:** I just gave an example. Usually the `val a` has tens of `scala.Tuple2`

Comment: How about `(1, 6, 7)`? Are there exactly two input tuples (why are they in a list then)?

Comment: sorry. It is already there. it is same as (6,7,1)

Comment: Are the elements in the input tuples all distinct?

Comment: yes they are. tuples and individual elements in val a = ListBuffer((1, 5), (6, 7)) are distinct. tuples3 and their individual element are also distinct.

Comment: Does this need to work for more than two tuples or for longer tuples? If not, you can just write out the four combinations (they will be distinct since all input elements are distinct). `case Seq((a,b),(c,d)) => Seq((a,b,c),(a,b,d),(c,d,a),(c,d,b))`

Comment: Yes it should work for more than two tuples. I just gave an example for simplicity and understanding

Comment: If you want `(1,7,6)` to be considered equal to `(6,7,1)` then why are these tuples? Wouldn't a `Set(1,6,7)` be better?

Comment: actually its because I have inputs as list of tuples! I was thinking many times about set but how will I make it working with tuples to get the same result as in question above?

Comment: See @jwvh's answer for how to turn tuples into collections and back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the individual elements are unique, as you've commented, then you should be able to flatten everything (un-tuple), get the desired `combinations()`, and re-tuple.

**updated**

```
val a = collection.mutable.ListBuffer((1, 4), (1, 5))
a.flatMap(t => Seq(t._1, t._2))     //un-tuple
  .distinct                         //no duplicates
  .combinations(3)                  //unique sets of 3
  .map{case Seq(x,y,z) => (x,y,z)}  //re-tuple
  .toList                           //if you don't want an iterator
```

Comment: This will also make combinations taking one element each from three input tuples (not just two from one and one from another). That is probably what was intended. It can also re-order the two elements it takes from a single tuple (so that (1,2)+(3,4) can become (2,1,3) instead of (1,2,3)). Not sure if that is intended. @Khaled needs to clarify if component ordering is important and why these are tuples in the first place (instead of just Lists or Sets).

Comment: they are unique inside the tuple but not outside. I mean it can be (1,4) (1,5) but not (1,1) (1,5).

Comment: In this example, you want the result to include `(1,4,1)`?

Comment: no, it should be ignored. elements inside the tuple should be unique, so `(1,4,1)` is removed or discarded.

Comment: I made an update to the question. sorry if it was not clear in the beginning. so lets say the input is `(1,4) (1,5)`  then the output should be `(1,4,5)` with discarding `(1,4,1) and (1,5,1) `

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Just have a question: I wanted also to generalize your answer so I make it work with list of lists `a.flatMap(t => t).distinct.combinations(3).map{case Seq(x,y,z) => ListBuffer(x,y,z)}.to[ListBuffer]`. **The question is:** if I define val n = 3 and I put .combinations(n) instead of .combinations(3), how can I generate `Seq` with `n` variables instead of make it fixed such as `(x,y,z)`?

Comment: The problem with generalizing for `combinations(n)` is the requirement that the result set be in a tuple. A `Seq` of any size is still the same type; not so with tuples. Type `Tuple3` is different, and unrelated (or semi-related), to type `Tuple4`. It is possible to make it _look_ like the code is generalized over tuples, but it actually just hides the type-specific code behind implicits, and requires a lot more code than what you see here.